# Tomcat on windows10 vs ubuntu url parameter arrays = 400 bad request

Tags: tomcat

I have this issue on windows 10 tomcat 8 but not on Ubuntu
When sending any request with an array parameters it throw bad request 400
Even though the manager request
http://localhost:8080?area[]=5
Any idea and how to fix it ?

Comment: Looks like your client doesn't know how to properly url-encode those brackets. What is the client?

Comment: I have followed the tomcat spec and removed the brackets and it worked properly
But I am still surprised: since this is implemented in windows, why it is not implemented like that on linux/ubuntu ?
It is the same project just moved from ubuntu to windows

Comment: It comes down to the client. *What is the client*? You *can* use brackets in your URLs, but they must be properly-encoded.

Comment: Client was simply the browser. I used  chrome , IE, and firefox.

Comment: Are you sure you are using the exact same version of Tomcat on both systems? There was a recent change that has been causing lots of excitement. See https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=62273 for some good information about the problem and potential solutions. Your Tomcat version number is critical, here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Newer Tomcat  (7.0.73, 8.0.39, 8.5.7) use a stricter implementation of RFC 7230 and RFC 3986. Invalid character will be rejected by 400 response.

For a quick fix. You can.

1. Downgrade tomcat to one of older versions.
2. Use encodeURI on client.
3. Use method POST on client.